# How do I set properties of jpeg file in Xamarin for Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, jpeg, exif

I am working with jpeg files, when I look at the details of a jpeg file under windows (right-click->properties), under the Details tab there are entries for Title, Subject, Rating, Tags, Comments, etc.
How can I set these properties in Xamarin (Android)?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer on what you're trying to achieve?

Are you trying to set these properties from within your IDE? Or are you looking for a way to have a Xamarin developed app set these properties?

Comment: I am trying to set the properties within the C# code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code to guide you.

```
ExifInterface newExif= new ExifInterface(filePath);
newExif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLatitude, "teste lat");
newExif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLatitudeRef, "teste lat ref");
newExif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLongitude, "teste long");
newExif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagGpsLongitudeRef, "teste long ref");
newExif.SaveAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android.Media.ExifInterface for getting/setting Exif Properties in Xamarin.Android.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Comment: But how do I use the Java stuff with in the C# code. Also looking at the exif tags, I cant see anything to do with title, subject, comment that I can see in the properties of the file under windows explorer.